Two unit fractions that add up to $\frac{1}{a}$
How do you find the maximum number of pairs of unit fractions that add up to, let's say, $\frac{1}{12}$? This question is closely related to egyptian fractions, or the Erdős–Graham problem. Hope that helps!

Not sure what "maximum" means here.  Do you just mean that you want the number of pairs of unit fractions that sum to the given target?

I am not sure what you mean by "the maximum number of pairs of unit fractions that add up to $\frac{1}{2}$", but it is possible to use arbitrarily many unit fractions whose sum equals $\frac{1}{2}$.
For example, since $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6}$, and using the identity $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$, we can see that $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{n+1}$.
Therefore, $\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6 \cdot 7} + \frac{1}{7}$, which implies
$$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{42},$$
and so on.

The question asks for pairs of unit fractions – the title asks for two unit fractions – so I think what you've written doesn't engage with the question.

Extending from @RFZ's answer, you can write the fraction $1/n$ as:
$$\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n+r}+\frac{r}{n(n+r)}$$
For both of them to be unit fractions, $n(n+r)$ should be divisible by $r$. The number of $r$ values that satisfy this condition is your required answer.

$r$ divides $n(n+r)$ if and only if $r$ divides $n^2$.

Yes, so the number of pairs will be the number of factors of $n^2$, ceil divided by $2$ to remove duplicates.
